# How Cooper pairs conduct curent

Tags: solid-state-physics, electric-current, superconductivity

we know that electrons in superconductor are coupled somehow ([How does Cooper pairing work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102498/how-does-cooper-pairing-work))
  creating quasi-particles called **cooper pairs** which are Bosons and going to ground state ( do not obey Pauli exclusion anymore)

and that happen after this?.. how can be charge was cared without any dissipation?

Comment: thank you @JohnRennie , your answer is that I looking for :)